# I am getting error when I am compiling xmlbeans : java io.ioexception cannot run the program "javac"

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, xmlbeans

I am trying to run a sample of xmlBeans to compile a xsd and create a jar corresponding to that but I am getting this error again & again

```
java.io.Exception: Cannot run program "filelocation\javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start
    ............
```

It might be related to my "path" or "classpath" environment variable. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to the issue

I was using a command

> scomp  -out  automobile-policy.jar automobile-policy.xsd

but there was some problem with the javac location in the path variable i guess

So I gave this command

> scomp -compiler "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6\bin\javac.exe" -out 
>   automobile-policy.jar automobile-policy.xsd

and it gave the desired automobile-policy.jar at the location.

> Please note that the location of the javac.exe might be different.